# How to repeat an element based on databind value in the template

Tags: knockout.js

Tried but failed to find solution on the net. Hoping someone here knows.

I want to find a solution in the template itself without doing computed functions.

Here's an example with **NumberPeople=5**.

```
<div id="listpeople" data-bind="text:NumberPeople"></div>
```

Is there a way to show 5 icons inside the **listpeople** div? So end result would be:

```
<div id="listpeople" data-bind="{code here}">
    <span id="1">1</span>
    <span id="2">2</span>
    <span id="3">3</span>
    <span id="4">4</span>
    <span id="5">5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want a span 1-5 as the output? Or a span 1-5 for each of the 5 indicated by that number?

Comment: I am okay with just span 1-5 as the output as well! Like? <span class="person"></span><span class="person"></span><span class="person"></span><span class="person"></span>

Comment: Have you looked at the foreach binding at all?  Why not just do data-bind="foreach: people"?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems very artificial without any context, so the answers are probably going to be a bit artificial. Here's one way to do what you seem to be asking for:

```html
<div id="listpeople" data-bind="foreach: new Array(NumberPeople)">
    <span data-bind="text: $index()+1, attr: {id: $index()+1}"></span>
</div>
```

View models are simple, no computed functions:

```
var vm = { NumberPeople: 5 };
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkKxw/).

I do speculate the above may not be exactly right for what you're trying to achieve. If so you may be experiencing the [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If not: enjoy! :D

Comment: Brilliant! Much appreciated. Bonus question: Is there a way to limit it to less than 10 items in the foreach?

Comment: Hmm.. maybe you are right and this is not quite what I was looking for. The NumberPeople is actually part of the JSON knockout databind as well... I was hoping to use that to do the array.

Comment: If your question actually would've been quite different with additional information you'll probably be best off asking a fresh one. That way this question will remain useful to others with *this specific* problem, and your new question will pop up freshly in the unanswered questions queue. Be sure to include enough context though! Good luck.